# Expect assertions type error -> expect(...).toExist is not a function

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I'm testing a NodeJS app. I encountered this error when I ran the tests. The test script is below:

```js
.expect((res) => {
    expect(res.headers['x-auth']).toExist();
    expect(res.body._id).toExist();
    expect(res.body.email).toBe(email);
})
```

The error showed:

```
TypeError: expect(...).toExist is not a function
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: expect.js doesn't have any method called `toExist()`. You can read its documentation here: https://github.com/Automattic/expect.js

Comment: show your import/require statement.

Comment: @Svenskunganka following this documentation for testing .. other assertions are working fine ->  https://github.com/mjackson/expect

Comment: @FazalRasel const expect = require('expect');

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The expect assertion library has changed ownership. It was handed over to the Jest team, who in their infinite wisdom, created a new [API](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html).

You must now use [`toBeTruthy()`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#tobetruthy)instead of `toExist()`.

You can still install `expect` as before, `npm install expect --save-dev`, which is currently at version 21.2.1. Most methods names will remain unchanged except for a few, including `toExist()`.

Comment: not worked :/ expect(...). toBeTruthy() is not a function

Comment: its worked :) thanks a lot. I used .toContain() instead of .toInclude() but it does not match as expected @AKenny

Comment: If you are testing that an object contains certain properties and values, you could try using .toMatchObject)(obj).

Comment: I was just looking for this answer. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Jest you can also use 'toBeDefined()'