# Expect libarary TypeError: expect(...).toInclude is not a function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, supertest

I'm guessing it's an import error somehow, but I can't seem to figure out how, expect is up to date and I can't get it too run without it saying

> libarary TypeError: expect(...).toInclude is not a function

```
var request = require("supertest");
var {app} = require("./../server.js");
var {Show} = require("./../models/show");
var expect = require('expect');

    describe("GET /show/:id", () => {
        it("Should include the show name 'Arrow' in the body", (done) => {
            request(app)
            .get(`/show/${showName}`)
            .expect(200)
            .expect((res) => {
                expect('hello world').toInclude('world')

            })
            .end(done);
        });
    })

});
```

Comment: one of it's alias's works for me "toContain", I don't know if toInclude is not in the module anymore, if you know please let me know

Comment: The answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46459995/1424833 may help.

Comment: @MattHolland I guess that's it, I don't see the method toInclude in there, thanks for sharing that. If you would want to post the answer referencing that API and i'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `expect` library was recently made part of the [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/) project - the Jest team changed the API a little, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46459995/1424833) explains.

The full documentation for `expect` can now be found here: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html

Answer (score 10):

**UPDATE**: 
besides `.toMatchObject`, you can also use `.toHaveProperty`

---

For anyone who used `.toInclude` to check if an object contains certain fields, the new version is `.toMatchObject`.

Here is the document [reference](http://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect.html#tomatchobjectobject)

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing similar problem than it can be solved by importing `jest-dom` in your test file:
`import '@testing-library/jest-dom'` in your `xyz.test.js`

> Don't forget to install `jest-dom` in order to use it with jest:

```
npm i --save-dev @testing-library/jest-dom
```

Hope it helps.. :)